# Unable to access class attribute in another function

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, ros, python-3.8, rospy

```
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu

class ImuData:
    def __init__(self):
        #self.data = None
        pass

    def get_observation(self):
        rospy.Subscriber('/imu', Imu, self.imu_callback)
        imuData = self.data
        print(imuData)

    def imu_callback(self, msg):
        self.data = msg.orientation
        print(self.data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('gett_imu', anonymous= True)
    idd = ImuData()
    idd.get_observation()
```

In the above code, I would like to access `self.data` defined in `imu_callback` from `get_observation` function. The problem is I get error saying that `ImuData` has no attribute `data`.
How do I solve this issue?

Note: I feel that the question has to do with the python classes and not with Ros and rospy.

Comment: This would happen if you call `get_observation` before calling `imu_callback`. It's generally a bad idea to initialize attributes outside the `__init__` for this very reason.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are going on here. One, that was mentioned in the comment, is that you should be initializing your attributes inside `__init__`. The error your seeing is partially because of Python and the fact that `self.data` has not actually been initialized yet.

The second issue you have is where you setup the subscriber. This should also be done in `__init__` and only once. Sensors will be publishing at a fairly constant rate, thus it takes time to actually receive any data on the topic. Also if you plan to call `get_observation` more than once you would create a new subscription, which you do not want.

Take the following code as a fixed example:

```
    def __init__(self):
        rospy.Subscriber('/imu', Imu, self.imu_callback)
        self.data = None

    def get_observation(self):
        imuData = self.data
        print(imuData)
```